# Assigning results of groupby multiple indices, apply custom function, back to parent dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in which I want to groupby 2 columns, subtract even from odd rows of a 3rd column in each group, and assign results to a column in the original dataframe. Nothing I try from other answers quite seems to work for me though.

Example dataframe:

```
    ID Day OtherInfo log_timestamp
    A  17   foo       t1
    A  17   bar       t2
    A  18   footoo    t3
    A  18   bar_bar   t4
```

where log_timestamp is a datetime object.

The result I want should look something like:

```
    ID Day OtherInfo log_timestamp duration
    A  17   foo       t1           (t2-t1)
    A  17   bar       t2 
    A  18   footoo    t3            (t4-t3)
    A  18   bar_bar   t4
```

I have tried combinations of defining my own function, using a lambda function, and using "apply", "agg", "map", and "transform" but am not quite getting it.

```py
>>>my_df['duration'] = my_df.groupby(['ID', 'day'])['log_timestamp'].agg({'duration': lambda series: (series - series.shift())[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)})
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

>>>my_df['duration'] = my_df['day'].map(my_df.groupby(['ID', 'day'])['log_timestamp'].apply({'duration': lambda series: (series - series.shift())[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)}))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

>>>my_df['duration'] = my_df.groupby(['ID', 'day'])['log_timestamp'].transform(lambda series: (series - series.shift())[1::2].reset_index(drop=True))
ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the followitg test DataFrame (with "true" timestamps):

```
  ID  Day OtherInfo       log_timestamp
0  A   17       foo 2019-09-01 10:20:00
1  A   17       bar 2019-09-01 11:30:00
2  A   18    footoo 2019-09-01 15:10:00
3  A   18   bar_bar 2019-09-01 15:55:00
```

Start from defining a function computing 2 result values
from 2 source values (timestamps):

```
def fn(grp):
    return [grp.iloc[1] - grp.iloc[0], np.nan]
```

The first returned value is the difference and the second - *NaN*.

The use it the following way:

```
df['duration'] = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 2)\
    .log_timestamp.transform(fn)
```

The result is:

```
  ID  Day OtherInfo       log_timestamp duration
0  A   17       foo 2019-09-01 10:20:00 01:10:00
1  A   17       bar 2019-09-01 11:30:00      NaT
2  A   18    footoo 2019-09-01 15:10:00 00:45:00
3  A   18   bar_bar 2019-09-01 15:55:00      NaT
```

*groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 2)* is a pandasonic "idiom" to
group a *DataFrame* (or a *Series*) into groups by 2 rows (or elements).

Then *transform(fn)* generates a sequence of values, something like
a "copy" of the original sequence (a pair of timestamps).

So the first returned value - the difference between both timestamps - is
the new value for the first element and *NaN* - for the second.

Because the destination column is of *Timestamp* type, the *NaN* is
converted to *NaT*.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution, however one clarification: do I need to first import numpy as np ?  Or what is np?

Comment: Yes, you should *import numpy as np*. *Pandas* is built "on top of Numpy", so it uses some constants definded there.

Comment: An alternative: instead of *np.nan* you can use just *None*. No need to import *Numpy* and result is just the same.